# Get Timezone using method FindSystemTimeZoneById not returning proper Timezone object

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I am using method to get timezone from TimeZoneId

```
var timezoneObject= TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC");
```

What I am expecting as

```
timezoneObject.Id : UTC
timezoneObject.DisplayName :(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time
timezoneObject.StandardName: Coordinated Universal Time
timezoneObject.DaylightName: Coordinated Universal Time
```

but I am getting result as

```
timezoneObject.Id : UTC
timezoneObject.DisplayName :UTC
timezoneObject.StandardName: UTC
timezoneObject.DaylightName: UTC
```

But in case of

```
var timezoneObject= TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Dateline Standard Time");
```

its giving desired output.

Comment: Timezone info comes from the registry.  Except for "UTC", [that is intercepted early](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timezoneinfo.cs,d48f12bc885a787a).  The source code suggests that there might be Windows versions that don't have it in the registry.  Not sure if that is accurate, I could however imagine programmers that solved their datetime problem by editing the registry :)  Feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get your desired result by using this method:

```
var timezoneObject = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id == "UTC");
```

Ouput:

```
timezoneObject.Id : UTC
timezoneObject.DisplayName :(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time
timezoneObject.StandardName: Coordinated Universal Time
timezoneObject.DaylightName: Coordinated Universal Time
```

From Docs:

> The id parameter must correspond exactly to the time zone's registry
>   key in length, but not in case, for a successful match to occur; that
>   is, the comparison of id with time zone identifiers is
>   case-insensitive. If you want to retrieve time zone objects based on
>   partial matches, you can write custom procedures that work with the
>   read-only collection of TimeZoneInfo objects returned by the
>   GetSystemTimeZones method.